# change img that in class in class in id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, click, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I read about it but still I'm not able to make it work.
I have an image (empty heart) that I would like to change to a different image (full heart) in order to indicate it was added to the wish list.

here is my code:

```
 <tbody class="mainImgs">
     <div ng-repeat="party in showtop5" ng-class=party.name>
       <img ng-src="{{party.image}}">
       <h2 id="title">{{party.title}}</h2>
       <h3 id="description">{{party.description}}</h2>
       <button href="#" class="imageClick" ng-click="click(party.title, party.description, party.image)">
         <img ng-src="../images/emptyHeart.png" id="heart" click="myFunction(party.name, imageClick)">
       </button>
       <img ng-src="{{party.img}}" id="pace">
     </div>
 </tbody>
```

and my script:

```
   function myFunction(myclass1, myclass2){
        document.getElementByClass(myclass1).getElementByClass(myclass2).getElementById("heart").src = "../images/fullHeart.png";
     }
```

what did I do wrong? 
without sending the class - and trying to find image only by id - t works only for the first object heart that is printed

Comment: Why are u mixing angular with normal javascript eg: `click="myFunction(party.name, imageClick)"` its not the right approach. U might need to apply `$apply` in some unwanted situation, u never know

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Change that certain img only, the one you clicked on?

Comment: yes @TheDarkKnight

Comment: Also, use `ng-src` when using angular expression `{{someVal}}` else there is no point in using `ng-src` for simple string

Comment: Move what is inside your myFunction into the click function, since the image is inside the button, the function is never being called.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I changed it to ng-click and moved it to angular as I was suggested, but the problem is that now all of them are colored.
I have the index of the one that was clicked by using $index, can that help me with the  $scope.imgPath solution?

Comment: Can we safely assume that party.name will not be repeated? If so, could you just add that class to the image? And get specifically the img itself like so: `document.getElementsByTagName("IMG").getElementByClass(party.name).getElementById("heart").src = "../images/fullHeart.png";` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think if its just about changing image then it can be handled pretty straight forward:

**In html**

```
<button href="#" class="imageClick" ng-click="click(party.title, party.description, party.image)">
   <img ng-src="{{imgPath}}" id="heart" ng-click="myFunction(party.name, imageClick)">
</button>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.imgPath = "../images/emptyHeart.png";
$scope.myFunction= function (name,imageClick){
   // use promise to monitor the server response of adding product to Wishlist
  ("YOUR_PROMISE_CALL").then(
     function(success){
        $scope.imgPath = "../images/fullHeart.png";   // Bingo !!
     },
    function(error){
        // take appropriate action
     },
  )
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that there are multiple images, each handled individually. Either way, myFunction will never get called, see this simple jsbin I made to test it:http://jsbin.com/cuduyuzoto/edit?html,js,console,output; Only the button click is being read, which might be the actual problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. my problem is that it colors know all the hearts I have and not only the one that was clicked... how do I solve it?